Extracting non-zero coefficient in lrn("surv.penalized")
I'm doing an ML study. I've used surv.penalized for lasso Penalized Cox Regression Learner, and get the non-zero coefficients. And it seems to work i.e. I do get some non-zero coefficients and the rest go to zero. Is there a way to extract coefficients and their names that are not zero?
my codes as follows:
``` r
library(mlr3extralearners)
library(mlr3proba)
#> Loading required package: mlr3


task = tsk("rats")
penalized =lrn("surv.penalized", lambda1=16.86)
penalized$train(task)
#> Warning: package 'survival' was built under R version 4.4.1
#> # nonzero coefficients: 3# nonzero coefficients: 2          # nonzero coefficients: 2          # nonzero coefficients: 2          # nonzero coefficients: 2          # nonzero coefficients: 2          

<sup>Created on 2024-07-10 with reprex v2.1.0</sup>

I want to extract the name and value of non-zero coefficients. How can I do that?

Hi! Please see answer below!

here is how you can do it (update Nov 2024):
library(mlr3extralearners)
#> Loading required package: mlr3
library(mlr3pipelines)
library(mlr3proba)

task = tsk("rats") # has one factor feature
# create graph learner
grlrn = 
  po("encode", method = "treatment") %>>% # encode factor
  lrn("surv.penalized", lambda1 = 16.86) |> 
  as_learner()
grlrn$train(task)
# the pipeline "knows" that the `base_learner()` is the penalized leanrer
# so you access that to ask for the selected features
grlrn$base_learner()$selected_features()
#> [1] "litter" "sex"

# more manually
penalized::coef(grlrn$model$surv.penalized$model$model)
#>       litter          sex 
#>  0.007091497 -0.247230755

Created on 2024-11-01 with reprex v2.1.1

@Faiza can you accept the answer? Thanks!
